# A non-existent config entity name returned by FieldStorageConfigInterface::getBundles():

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-modules

In Drupal Application Some one deleted the body field from field configuration. I tried to regenerate the body field. It's generating "field_body' as machine name.

**A non-existent config entity name returned by FieldStorageConfigInterface::getBundles(): entity type: node, bundle: ways_to_give, field name: body**

Comment: Try [solution #27 on the issue on Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2916266#comment-13292415). Using MySQL queries to remove errors is a dangerous way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a similar issue:

I am getting the message ;

A non-existent config entity name returned by FieldStorageConfigInterface::getBundles(): entity type: brick, bundle: content, field name: field_inmail

This seems to be related to 
https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2916266

Following the instructions there I used
SELECT * FROM `key_value` WHERE `value` LIKE '%field_inmail%'
But it gives me 5 rows and I cannot see which one I should or could delete or change  to fix the issue.

You might try something like 
SELECT * FROM `key_value` WHERE `value` LIKE '%body%';
If you only have one row you may be able to just delete or edit the row in the table. (please make a backup first)

You may need to look at the field result of Value which is a BLOB type string. Look at its string content and you should see the bundle names and the field that you are searching for. If you are using PHPMyAdmin you may have to right click that value and save as a bin file. You can open with texteditor it should be json text.

Let me know how you fixed this issue.